# Adobe AIR application maximization problem

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, screen, maximize

I have an application developed using Adobe AIR. If the target machine is using Windows XP it's working as expected, coming properly on the screen in both the Minimized and Maximized states. But when try the same application in Windows 7, particularly in Maximize mode, my application is going out of the screen. Bottom and top edges are little bit out of the screen.
I have tried to set the x, y coordinates to define the start position of the window and i have also tried to reduce the width of the application. Both the approaches didn't workout for me and moreover they have introduced few more issues.

Anybody faced the same issue with AIR applications and windows 7?

Please somebody help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you are using the system chrome for your AIR application, the height/width of the  OS chrome bars is in addition to the stage width/height. Thus if you set the stage's height/width to maximum - it will definitely cause a problem. Similarly, when setting (x, y) for the stage top.

I don't use Windows 7 so can't give you the numbers - but what you can do is drag the window to the middle of the screen, click a snap, check the height and width of top and left side of OS chrome in paintbrush. Now deduct the same from (and also for bottom and right) from the stage height/width. Set the (x, y) to the top and left values.

This is what I did on Windows Vista!

Comment: I think, you didn't get my point or i understood wrong. Top and bottom sides of my chrome less window are doing out of the screen. Right and Left sides are fine only.

Comment: What height are you setting the stage to? You might have to account for height changes of the windows task bar in Windows 7 - which is more than the previous versions of Windows.

Which Flex SDK and AIR SDK are you on, so that I can try something on my side.

Comment: I am not setting any height. Initially for the first time, i am displaying a small window of size 759,396. But after user enters the proper credentials, i am just maximizing the window by using maximize() function. Both the windows are chrome less only. I am using Flex Framework 3.4, Builder 3 and AIR SDK 2.6.